# JavaScript: efficiently create empty 2D array based on input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an array of empty arrays, the amount of which depends on N. Currently, I have this:

```
var seqList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    seqList.push([]);
}
```

Is this the most efficient way of doing it? Or might there be another way?

Comment: Efficient in what way? Less code, better readable code, faster running code, etc.?

Comment: I was thinking faster running. I know it's not like it's horrendously slow, but if there was a huge value for N, I was just wondering if there was some method that would be a little faster that I don't know about.

Comment: Why are you optimizing something that you aren't positive needs optimization? Do some measurements first and see if any of the expected values for N actually cause problems and verify that this part of the code is the bottleneck, then proceed with ways to optimize. If you need to optimize this, I don't think there is a magical method that would make it much faster, unless you do a custom implementation and use a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is the most efficient one. You can also use `Array.fill` method from `ES6` but it is not the most efficient.

```js
let n=10;
let array=Array.from({ length: n }, () => []);
console.log(array);
```

When you are using `let array=[]` you're telling the interpreter to create a new runtime array.

If you use:`var a = new Array()` you're telling the interpreterthat you want to call the constructor `Array` , generate an object and creating your array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is the cleanest

```
let count = 10;
let seqList = Array(count).fill([]);
```

**Update:**

After being schooled by @deceze I would rather use since the example above fails is a horribly subtle way.

```
let count = 10;
let seqList = Array(count).fill(0).map(_ => []);
```

Is it better than your attempt? Probably not. I've just become so used to reading map/reduce, I prefer it. YMMV

Comment: `seqList[0].push('foo')`… try it.

Comment: @deceze Why would you need to ```push```?. Per the question the size "depends on N"

Comment: Try. It. Then `console.log(seqList)`. Then you'll see the problem with this approach.

Comment: @deceze. Very interesting. I've used it hundreds of times in production code and never had and issue. But then I usually ```map``` from it. Thanks for the heads-up